# Using Django-Registration, what's the easiest way to remove and use email address

Tags: django, django-registration

For my app, I'd just like people to register with an email address and password and use that to log in. Essentially I dont want the username to ever be seen by the end user.

I'm using django-registration. Is there a super simple way to set it this way?  Seems like a fairly common need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1001/

Answer (score 0):

In your registration form, you'll need to remove the username and have it be autogenerated. The username field isn't very long in Django so just using an email isn't a viable option without (monkey)patching Django.

Once you are registering users with a autogenerated username, you'll need to enable authenication. To do this you need to use a custom Authentication backend that enables signing in by email. Pinax has one that you can use as a reference:

[Link](https://github.com/pinax/pinax/blob/master/pinax/apps/account/auth_backends.py)